Do wireless power transfer coils have polarity?
This question is a continuation of my previous topic.
I need to characterize this coil with the help of this document.
The coil will be connected to a BNC adapter and the other end of the cable is connected to a Bode100.

The red circle shows the positive terminal of the BNC adapter and the other one is the negative terminal.
Below is the image of the coil with the wires circled needed for my application.

Do these wires have any polarity or can I connect any of these wires to the positive terminal of the BNC adapter?


The red circle shows the positive terminal of the BNC adapter and the
other one is the negative terminal.

That is incorrect; one terminal connects to the outer screen of the coaxial cable cable (via the BNC connector) and, the other terminal connects to the coaxial cable inner conductor (also via the BNC connector).
There can be nothing that is polarized about a signal that drives the coil because that would imply a DC voltage across an inductor and that would mean massive excessive DC currents.
Neither is there any sense in regarding the input to the analyser as being polarized; it will be a purely AC waveform.

Do these wires have any polarity or can I connect any of these wires
to the positive terminal of the BNC adapter?

They do not have any polarity and, you can reverse the connections to the analyser without concern. The only effect will be an inversion of the received signal and, that is of trivial consequence for wireless power transfer using that particular coil mentioned in your question.

May I Know can we use same coil for RX and TX

@Confused you should be able to but, it's totally application driven. I've got a design that uses a single turn 10 inch square coil for transmit and a 7 mm diameter bobbin inductor for the receiver so, like I say, it depends on the application.

As simple single coil driven with an AC waveform, they have no polarity.
If you were driving multiple coils (some WPT xmitters have e.g. three coils overlapped to increase area/power), you would need to be more careful to ensure all of the coils were correctly phased to avoid cancellation.

Than you very much.I am new to WPT. If you don't mind can you please tell me what you mean by "ensure all of the coils were correctly phased "
